# Activate jQuery function after clicking JavaScript popup box link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, calendar, popup

My form contains a text field that accepts a date in the format MM/DD/YYYY. When you click the text field, a small JS calendar appears and you can click the date and it fills in the text field.

I need to activate a jQuery function after the text field receives the date from the JS calendar popup.

I've tried change, val, mouseup, mousedown, live, etc. but suspect that I will need to listen for an event from the JS calendar. Interestingly, each of these actions work the second time I click the calendar, but not the first (so I click the calendar date and it fills in the field, then I click it again and pick another date and the jQuery function runs).

Any ideas?

```
$('#input_field_id').change(validate_function);
```

Calendar:
http://mattkruse.com/javascript/calendarpopup/

Comment: post your code what you've tried

Comment: What are you using for the small JS calendar? A plugin? Some code would help here.

Comment: which calendar you are using?

Answer (score 2):

I hope it can help you :

HTML code:

```
    <label>Date:</label> <input type="text" id="date" />
```

Script in head :

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#date" ).datepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

And also need you include some too :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$('.cpCurrentDate).bind('click',function(){
//your code here
});

$('.cpOtherMonthDate'').bind('click',function(){
//your code here
});
```

Or combined one will be,

```
$('.cpCurrentDate, .cpOtherMonthDate').bind('click',function(){
//your code here
});
```

Comment: you want to call some function when date is clicked using calender right?

Comment: Right. I'm using "Default calendar using the DIV-style display." When the date is clicked in the calendar, it fills in a text field with MM/DD/YYYY. I want to call the jQuery function when the date is filled in.

Comment: on click of any date(which have class `.cpCurrentDate` or `.cpOtherMonthDate`) there are two functions getting called i.e. `CP_tmpReturnFunction("selected date as parameter")` and `CP_hideCalendar(1)`.
SO there are two ways:
1)Write Your code inside any of above two function.
2)Or write the code onclick of anydate which i gave you in my main answer.

Comment: Or write the code onclick of anydate which i gave you in my main answer....I tried that but it isn't working. Are you sure that jQuery can access the classes in the JS calendar?

Comment: offcourse..!!!your dates are written inside `<td>` as an anchor.and you have onclick function for anchor.so it should work.where you have written your code in page?is there any error in console

Comment: The code is written at the top of the page. I have a select menu on the page as well and it can activate the validate function for the text field on "change." So it is working, just not when I use the JS calendar to select the date. I'm not sure what you mean about anchors and onclick function. The JS calendar source file shows A HREF links inside <td>.

Comment: your a tag defines hyperlinks.im sure you must have added some js file for calender picker?try writing the code inside it.

Comment: I'm using the second example at the link above: " Default calendar using the DIV-style display."

Comment: try writing that code inside `pageload` event or inside calendarpopup.js file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to bind the input field with the change event, just like you have in your sample.

```
$('#dateField').bind('change', function(e) {
    var date = $(this).val();
    // validate your date
});
```

This will give trigger when the input value is changed by a person.

If the date is getting injected into the input field, you'll have to trigger the change event for that input field.

```
$('#dateField').val(dateFromCal).trigger('change');
```

When the input's value is set from the calendar it will then trigger the change event, which will then run your change event code.

Example provided: http://jsfiddle.net/KEFAL/1/

Comment: How do I get the new value from the JS calendar?

Comment: So you need the value of the calendar before it would be placed into the input field?

Comment: I'm not sure. The text field is filled in by the JS calendar (link above). I need to capture that event and activate my function.

Comment: Yes to do that you'll need to trigger a change event for the input field when the value is set by the calendar. But you'll need to see if there is the calendar provides a method that

Comment: How might I go about figuring that out? Thanks.

Comment: When I hover over the links in the calendar, I see this function: CP_tmpReturnFunction. Can I listen for this?

Comment: I didn't mean to cut off, but you'll have to see if the calendar provides a method to get the date or has callbacks before/after it sets/gets the date. You'll have to look at the documentation for the calendar or source. I lost internet on desktop and using my phone, otherwise I'd be like looking at the calendar source.